# Need help in figuring out mistake for solving problem on probabilities

Tags: probability

We draw 3 marbles from the following set of marbles: 10 white, 5 black, 4 orange. We get 2 dollars for each black ones, and we loose 1 dollar for each white one. X will denote money we will get/loose after a game. What are possible values of X and what are the probabilities for each value?

So my solution is:

(W, W, W) | X = -3 | 10/19 * 9/18 * 8/17 = 0.12384

(W, W, B) | X = 0 | 10/19 * 9/18 * 5/17 * 3 = 0.2322

(W, B, B) | X = 3 | 10/19 * 5/18 * 4/17 * 3 = 0.1032

(B, B, B) | X = 6 | 5/19 * 4/18 * 3/17 = 0.01032

(B, B, O) | X = 4 | 5/19 * 4/18 * 4/17 * 3 = 0.04128

(B, O, O) | X = 2 | 5/19 * 4/18 * 3/17 * 3 = 0.03096

(O, O, O) | X = 0 | 4/19 * 3/18 * 2/17 = 0.00413

(O, O, W) | X = -1 | 4/19 * 3/18 * 10/17 * 3 = 0.06192

(O, W, W) | X = -2 | 4/19 * 10/18 * 9/17 * 3 = 0.18576

(O, W, B) | X = 1  | 10/19 * 5/18 * 4/17  * 6 = 0.2064

So, all probabilities can be derived from the above table, except of P(X = 0), which is 0.2322 + 0.00413 = 0.23633

When I sum up all probabilities I am getting 0.94884 in total.. but I should get 1.0

Really need help to figure our what is wrong..  Thank you!

Comment: Check the line $(B, B, O)$

Comment: @peterwhy oh, it was a typo. now is it ok?

Comment: @peterwhy this typo did not affect the result because calculation was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the probability is defined as:

$$\frac{\text{# of cases that satisfy an event}}{\text{# of total cases in the sample space}}.$$
Try to think of it and to solve the problem in that way. For example: How would you get $X=1$? With a tuple of the form (O,B,W), which has probability $\dfrac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{10}{1}}{\binom{19}{3}}$, which in your case is correct. Now how would you get $X=0$? With a tuple of the form (O,O,O) or (B,W,W), which has probability $\dfrac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{19}{3}}+\dfrac{\binom{5}{1}\binom{10}{2}}{\binom{19}{3}} \approx 0.25696 \neq 0.2322+0.00413. $

I recommend you not to use calculator but to try to simplify by hand. In my calculator I get a lot of decimals and of course I'm not sure if the number I'm given by the calculator is correct or not. For instante $P(X=0)=\dfrac{83}{323}\approx 0.25696.$

Comment: so, why I cannot do for zero 
(W, W, B) + (O, O, O) =  10/19 * 9/18 * 5/17 * 3 

+ 4/19 * 3/18 * 2/17 = 0.2322 + 0.00413

What how is it different from what you offered?

Comment: When I say of the form (B,W,W) I mean the tuples: (B,W,W), (W,B,W), (W,W,B). What you are doing is to take the tuple (W,W,B), find its probability and multiply by $3$ assuming that the way you calculate the prob of (W,W,B) is the same as the way you calculate the prob of (W,B,W).

Comment: So it's different because $19*18*17\neq \binom{19}{3}$.